# Is the gas usage O(1) for this code?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-refund

Is the gas usage constant for this function regardless of mapping/array size (assuming non-zero array entries)?

`items` is an array, and `presence` is a mapping

```
function clear() public {
    for (uint i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        presence[items[i]] = 0;
    }

    delete items;
}
```

In other words, is the gas refund from deleting the data greater than the gas consumed when iterating and querying the data?

This function is a snippet from [this Set implementation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/104224/67306).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick analysis shows that the function call gas usage isn't O(1) and also isn't close to O(1). After more than 2 items, the gas usage starts rising for every additional item.

Here is a table of gas usage for clearing a varying number of items (tested using https://remix.ethereum.org):

| Number of items | Gas used to clear items |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 23823 |
| 1 | 18644 |
| 2 | 23976 |
| 3 | 29308 |
| 4 | 34640 |